Updating Old Code for a "Special Order" Item in PayPal Cart
I'm trying to fix some code on a site that uses PayPal's old shopping cart variables. Please bear with me, as I am not a developer :)...
One of the things that needs updating is a form that customers can use if they want to add a cart item (& price) themselves for something that isn't listed on the site.
Although this basically kind of works, it sometimes generates gibberish, particularly if a customer enters quotation marks:
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="merchant@invalid.com"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Add_Item"> 
    <span class="style1">Item Description:</span>
    <input name="item_name" type="text" value="" size="42" maxlength="70">
    <span class="style1">Amount: $</span>
    <input name="amount" type="text" value="" size="4" maxlength="7">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><p>
</form>

I realize that this code is outdated, but I'm not sure what to replace it with.
Any suggestions?

Can you clarify what specific problem you are trying to describe by "Although this basically kind of works, it sometimes generates gibberish"?  And how is PHP involved?  What you're showing is HTML.

Here is an example:
%93350k%2Btap%2Bsw%2C 1.2%94Featured book%94
Sorry if I posted this in the wrong place :(  ...I can move it if needed.

Perhaps that's a URL-encoded value for "350k+tap+sw,1.2Featuredbook"?  Where are you seeing that value and what produces that value?  What problem is encountered when using that value?  Please update the question to clarify.

My mistake... that should actually be:
%93350k%2Btap%2Bsw%2C 1.2%94Philco shaft%94 ...
I don't know exactly what the customer entered, but I'm guessing that it was something along the lines of " Philco 350k control. 1/4" shaft with tap and switch".

And that's a URL-encoded value for "350k+tap+sw, 1.2Philco shaft".  (Well, depending on the character set.  In a different set it's “350k+tap+sw, 1.2”Philco shaft” which may be more correct here.)  It's still not clear what actual problem you're trying to describe though.

Sorry if I wasn't clear; the merchant on the receiving end can't tell what the customer is adding to the cart because the output is scrambled. I'm trying to correct that.

It sounds like you're just looking to "URL-decode" the values then?  Wherever you're trying to use those values is where you'd do that.  The code shown simply sends to PayPal whatever information the user enters.  If the user enters sloppy data then the result is sloppy data.

Some follow up info: Apparently it usually happens if someone uses quotation marks.


this code is outdated, but I'm not sure what to replace it with.

You'll need to elaborate on what "generates gibberish" entails if you want help with the existing code, but for new code that can accomplish something similar create a "Pay link or button" logging in at https://www.paypal.com/buttons

The problem is that when you attempt to send a string like
Quote: "to be or not to be, that is the question"

then it will be sent as
"Quote: "to be or not to be, that is the question""

and the server will believe that the string it received was "Quote: ". You will either need to HTTP-encode it via encodeURIComponent
See:


function foo(text) {
    console.log(encodeURIComponent(text))
}

function bar(text) {
    console.log(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(text)));
}
<input type="text" disabled value='Quote: "to be or not to be, that is the question"'>
<input type="button" value="encode" onclick="foo(this.parentNode.querySelector('input').value)">
<input type="button" value="decode" onclick="bar(this.parentNode.querySelector('input').value)">



So you can encode or decode URI components as you please.
The gibberish you received is likely encoded text and you will likely need to decode it. If the POST is damaged because of the quotes, then register a submit event that handles this kind of issue.
